# Large Column Comparisons on jqGrid

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

The actual table is written in jqgrid.  I'm trying to figure out a way to quickly do a .equals() comparison on every line of each column.  If one of them turns out to be false, then I'm quickly going to throw a red background and an error message.

```
    1. Daniel Radcliff / Treecrest / 10
    2. Daniel Radcliff / Treecrest / 11
    3. Daniel Radcliff / Treecrest / 10
```

The 3rd column should throw the red background, but the others should be fine.  What's the most efficient solution?

Comment: Please would you kindly post a jsfiddle.

Comment: I wouldn't even be sure what to post on jsfiddle